# How to make tabs clickable at the top pixel of a snapped Firefox window?

Tags: firefox

I am used to select a Firefox tab at the topmost pixel (Fitts' law) and have used Firefox mostly in a maximized window so far, where this works perfectly.
After I upgraded to an ultrawide monitor, I will use Firefox only on a part of the monitor (but full height). In this non-maximized state, the top row of pixels is used to resize the window vertically (which I never use) and I have to move the mouse down a few pixels to hit the tab.

The question is how can I make Firefox behave as if maximized even in a non-maximized state, so that I can switch tabs by clicking the topmost pixel.

I don't mind modifying userChrome.css, using AutoHotKey, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only ever use Firefox in one position and size, you could use an extension that restores a pixel-perfect position. This position could be zero pixels from the top (or maybe even negative, if needed).

I would (of course ) recommend the extension I made, [ResizeIT 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/resizeit-2/). It was inspired by the original [ResizeIT extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/resizeit/). There are many alternatives, too. You’d want one that not only restores a size but also a position.

I use my own extension every day to center the Firefox window on my screen.

There are also tools that can save and restore window layouts in general, not limited to your browser. I don’t have any experience with them however, so I cannot recommend any.

Comment: Moving the window up is a great idea, thanks :) Your extension is a viable solution, but it would be even better to trigger the resizing by dragging the window instead of pressing a hotkey. Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Firefox extensions API does not offer a way to subscribe to window positions. So that’s not possible. Maybe with polling, but that would not create a good user experience.

Comment: Understood. I now using your extension and it definitely improves the browsing experience :) Also looking into AutoHotKey to make setting up window positions even easier.

Comment: For someone who wants to achive the same with AutoHotKey: Look into the `WinMove` command. E.g (for a 5120x1440 sceen):

    `!2::WinMove, A, , 1275, -3, 2570, 1410`